# Use variable passed to a function to call a member from a class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, variables

```
import nmap3

def nmap_scan(address,nmapType):
    nmap = nmap3.Nmap()
    result = f'nmap.{nmapType}({address})'
    #result = nmap.nmapType(address) gives the error nmap type is not a member of class nmap
    print(result)

nmap_scan(127.0.0.1,scan_top_ports) #user input will be given here
```

What I want the code to do is take user input on the type of scan he wants from the `python-nmap3` repo and use it as a variable in the `result = f'nmap.nmapType(address)'` line.

However, if I remove the f string, `python` treats `nmapType` variable as a method to the class `nmap`. What I want is the user to be able to specify the method name in the variable `nmapType`.

Is there a way around to solve this problem and use user input to call the correct `nmap` method based on user input?

I want the user to enter the scan type, pass that to `nmap_scan` function, and use it to perform the scan.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're trying to say. Please try to write more clearly and use distinct sentences.

Comment: what exactly is the error and seemingly it is telling you that you can't use `nmap.nmpaType` because that simply is not possible, did you read the docs?

Comment: Use `getattr` and pass `scan_top_ports` as a string. for example, `my_method = getattr(nmap, nmapType)` `my_method(address)`. To clarify, your function call should be `nmap_scan('127.0.0.1', 'scan_top_ports')`

Comment: nmap3 is a module I'm using in my code......I want the user to enter the type of scan he wants to perform on the target that I will pass on to the function call nmap_scan(127.0.0.1,scan_top_ports) and  use the variable nmapType to do different types of scan on the target but the problem I'm getting is that I don't know how to tell python that nmapType is variable I want to use in result = nmap.nmapType(address) and that it is not a function of class nmap. So how can I do that in python?